# Header for HTML Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating dynamic select in script.

```
 $.each(data, function (i) {

                                optionhtml = '<option value="' 
                            data[i].CustomerId + '">' + data[i].CustomerId + ' _  ' + data[i].PurchaseDate + ' _  ' + data[i].SupplyDate + ' _  ' + data[i].SupplierName + '</option>';
                                $("select[id='ddlAdm" + arrElem[0]']").append(optionhtml);
                            });
```

This works well. Select displays text in dropdown for CustomerId+PurchaseDate+SupplyDate+SupplierName

However I want to add header in select for this.

```
CustomerId PurchaseDate SupplyDate SupplierName
123         10/11/2016   10/15/2018  XYZ
123         10/16/2018   10/23/2018  PQR
```

I really want to skip autocomplete and typeahead plugin for this. Need to add header in select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add header to select element using **optgroup**

You can check demo [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/bgd9bobo/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/bgd9bobo/)

```
<select>
    <optgroup label = "CustomerId PurchaseDate SupplyDate SupplierName">
    <option value ="123         10/11/2016   10/15/2018  XYZ">123         10/11/2016   10/15/2018  XYZ</option>    
    <option value ="123         10/16/2018   10/23/2018  PQR">123         10/16/2018   10/23/2018  PQR</option>   
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, can it be modified so that it will look something similar to table structure, as this is not formattted well

Comment: Yes you can modified it.

Comment: You need to adjust space according to header

Comment: One more help, when user select an option, it should just display "CustomerId " e.g, "123" in the selected text and not the entire option e.g "123         10/11/2016   10/15/2018  XYZ". When user select an option it should display just ID

Comment: @JohnyBravo the question is answered. Please ask another question if you want to get another answer